# Is it possible to disable HTML5 constraint validation on specific input?

Tags: html, forms, validation

My problem is this:  `<input type='number' min='0' max='100' step='10'>`

Modern browsers uses the "step" attribute both to control the size of the spinner steps AND for client-side validation.
My users are generally entering a rough percentage, so steps of 10 are fine (and make the spinner more useful).  But I want them to be able to type in any integer between 0-100 -- the constraint validation pops an error and prevents form submission for values like "12" :-P

The form tag allows a novalidate attribute to prevent client-side validation on the entire form.  The JS API allows you to check IF an input will be validated.  But can you specify no validation for an individual input?  Or better yet, is it possible to prevent the Step Validation specifically?

BTW -- does anyone else find the spinners browsers put on `<input type='number'>` have very poor usability?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is my best guess so far:  https://jsfiddle.net/powderflask/cm79bkw4/   It does get rid of the validation message, but I have yet to find a way to tell the form this field is actually valid.  Seems .validity properties are read-only, and setCustomValidity() does not reset the validity during validation.  Rats!